# Print line number of text file

Tags: python

Very new to python and self teaching at the moment, so apologies if the example is wrong/basic.
Feel free to improve it :)

Basically the file MEs.txt contains a list of IP addresses, once it pings the ip address and gets a response I was trying to get the printout of 'ME (line number) is connected/disconnected).

Any help?

````
os.remove("EquipmentCheck.txt")

file = open("MEs.txt", "r+")

with open("MEs.txt", "r") as file:

  for line in file:
     response = os.system("ping   " + line)

     if response == 0:
        with open("EquipmentCheck.txt", "a") as file:
                file.write("ME is connected" "\n")

     else:
         with open("EquipmentCheck.txt", "a") as file:
                file.write("ME is disconnected" "\n")```
````

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: You're reusing the variable name `file` for several different filenames.  You probably want to use different variables.

Comment: @JohnGordon, and the second line doesn't do anything

Comment: you are opening the file twice, u can safely remove the line ` file = open("MEs.txt", "r+")`

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

```
  for index, line in enumerate(file):
     line_number = index + 1
     ...
```

Apparently there's a start parameter. So you could do:

```
  for line_number, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
     ...
```

Comment: That’s only of one multiple issues though, no?

Comment: I thought they were only looking for how to get the line number of the file that they iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

try with enumerate()

> enumerate(iterable, start=0)
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> **Iterable**: any object that supports iteration
> **Start**: the index value
> from which the counter is to be started, by default it is 0

```
with open("MEs.txt") as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        print("%d, %s"%(i, line))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 variables named file, they're breaking the code